# Como fazer quicksort "manual"

Tags: python, classificação, quicksort

Eu já fiz um *SelectionSort* manual em Pyhon veja abaixo:

```
lista = []
# digite 0 para encerrar a entrada de dados
while True:
  x = input('Entrada: ')
  if x == '0': break
  else: lista.append(x)
nota = []
for x in lista:
  nota.append(0)

# metodo SelectionSort
for a in range(len(lista)):
  for b in range(a + 1, len(lista)):
    while True:
      print('1: %s' % lista[a])
      print('2: %s' % lista[b])
      x = int(input('Digite: '))
      print()
      if x >= 0 and x <= 2: break
    if x == 1:
      nota[a] = nota[a] + 1
    elif x == 2:
      nota[b] = nota[b] + 1
```

Se voces executarem o código acima, voces perceberão que se tratar de *SelectionSort*, mas com uma diferença, o *SelectionSort* para a execução, para "perguntar" ao usuário quem é o maior item do vetor "lista" e reflete no vetor "nota".

Exemplo:

Imagine que eu coloque como entrada esse item: adulto, bebe, adolescente, criança. e faça a comparação em "quem é mais velho?"
Então o vetores lista ficará após a entrada:

```
lista = [adulto, bebe, adolencete, criança]  
nota = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

E após a comparação ficará assim:

```
lista = [adulto, bebe, adolencete, criança]  
nota = [3 , 0, 2, 1]
```

Mas queria fazer uma versão "quicksort", mas todas as tentativas que faço o quicksort comparar para mim.
Eu quero um "quicksort" que "pare" a executação e pergunte para mim quem é maior ou não, e reflita o vetor "nota"

Eu fiz uma versão quicksort, mas não sei aonde estou errando. (estou a 1 semana nisto)

```
lista = []
# digite 0 para encerrar a entrada de dados
while True:
  x = input('Entrada: ')
  if x == '0': break
  else: lista.append(x)

nota = []
for x in lista:
  nota.append(0)

# metodo Quicksort
def quick(vetor):
  if len(vetor) <= 1:
    return vetor
menor, igual, maior = [], [], []
meio = len(vetor) // 2
pivo = vetor[meio]
for x in vetor:
  while True:
    print('1: %s' % x)
    print('2: %s' % pivo)
    a = int(input('Digite: '))
    print()
    if a >= 0 and a <= 2: break
  if a == 2:
    menor.append(x)
    b = vetor.index(x)
    nota[b] = nota[b] + 1
  elif a == 1:
    maior.append(x)
    b = vetor.index(pivo)
    nota[b] = nota[b] + 1
  else: igual.append(x)
return quick(menor) + igual + quick(maior)
quick(lista)
```

Resolvido

Eu conseguir, o objtivo no meu algoritmo é usar Quicksort para classificar coisas do tipo, "Atrizes mais bonitas de Hollywood" ou "Melhor carro da minha vida", enfim, eu conseguir, veja a solução abaixo:

```
def perguntar(a, b):
while True:
  print('1: %s' % a)
  print('2: %s' % b)
  x = int(input('Digite: '))
  print()
  if x >= 0 and x <= 2: break
return x
def quick(v):
  if len(v) <= 1:
    return v
  else:
    less = []
    meio = []
    more = []
    n = len(v) // 2
    pivo = v[n]
    for i in v:
      if i == pivo:
        meio.append(i)
      else:
        r = perguntar(i, pivo)
        if r == 1:
          less.append(i)
        else:
          more.append(i)
    print(less,meio,more)
    print()
    return quick(less) + quick(meio) + quick(more)
def ver(lista):
  for x in range(len(lista)):
    print('%2d: %s' % (x+1, lista[x]))
while True:
  lista = []
  ## digite 0 para parar a entrada de dados.
  ## digite sair para parar.
  while True:
    x = input('Entrada: ')
    if x == '0' or x == 'sair': break
    else:
      if lista != 'sair':
        lista.append(x)
  lista = quick(lista)
  ver(lista)
  if x == 'sair': break
```

Quem quiser testar, use como entrada de dados:
Quais linguagens de programação mais gosta.
Quais pessoas são mais marcantes na sua vida.
Quais os melhores filmes que já assistiu.

agora vou fazer isto em C.

Comment: faltou comentar sobre qual o problema da sua tentativa. O que acontece? Dá erro? Dá o resultado errado? Como?

Comment: Dá erro, os resultado sai errado, mas na versão "selectionsort" sai certo

Comment: edite a pergunta, coloque essa informação... Junto coloque o exemplo de entrada que você usou qual pra testar, o resultado que deu e como seria o certo, aponte onde está o problema, tudo isso na pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado Nosklo, já editei a pergunta